# Is it possible to download ICESat2 images with Python/Tensorflow for a given time period?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, satellite-image

I want to download images from ICESat2 https://nsidc.org/data/icesat-2 for a given time period but so far I haven't been able to find a way to do so programatically in Python/Tensorflow. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is software library being developed to help automate retrieving IS2 data using Python:

https://github.com/icesat2py/icepyx